# How to identify that ButterCMS blog is updated?

Tags: api

In response of ButterCMS API while retrieving blog posts there is only timestamps are 'created' and 'published'. When the post is updated then 'created' or 'published' timestamps are not updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please refer the above link to understand how to ask questions in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of determining when a post was updated from the timestamp, but there's a way to setup webhooks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roger